# Hola soy nuevo en visual code y siempre que abro un archivo que descargo me dice esto y no sé que hacer

Tags: c, visual-studio

Los archivos son descargados, los abro en el programa y a la hora de correrlo en la terminal me da este mensaje [image]

Comment: Que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra el archivo que deseas, copia y pega la ruta de tu archivo y ve que pasa

Comment: Hola, uso Windows 10 y todos los archivos con los que trabajo los guardo en mi espacio de trabajo. El nombre de mi archivo tenía espacios se los quité y se solucionó aunque no sé por qué...

Comment: tranquilo, ese error es muy comun, espreferible usar otro metodo para separar como ```-```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar python deberías descargar las extensiones que necesites, a parte de descargar la última versión de la página oficial, pero si es c++ el que debes usar son más pasos los que debes hacer, con gusto te los puedo decir, como soy nuevo no me deja hacer comentarios.

Comment: Hola, creo que debe ser la versión, y de las extensiones creo tener todas las necesarias, trabajo con C